# Why is it invalid to cast an int to char with the as-operator?

Tags: c#, casting

In C# there are 2 ways of casting:

- `foo as int`
- `(int)foo`

Why does the first line not compile and the second does?

```
Console.Write(49 as char);
Console.Write((char)49);
```

Comment: So why delete it before anyone else could vote?

Comment: I expected this to end up with -10 and i don't wanna lose my comment privileges.

Comment: Don't delete before asking what's wrong ;)

Comment: Is this something that every developer knows and only  comes from students like me?

Comment: its not something everyone knows but it is something that with more experience you can figure out yourself form the compiler error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx):

> You can use the as operator to perform certain types of conversions between compatible reference types or [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

`char` is neither a reference type nor a nullable type. It can't set the output variable of `49` to `null` (when the conversion fails) since it isn't nullable. It would work with `char?` though, although useless in this situation.

Comment: What would work with `char?`? That's not a reference type either.

Comment: It is a [nullable type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) as referenced in the documentation.

Comment: @MikeT I am sure Lasse knows that. He is a very experienced .NET developer (see his list of answers). He just missed a piece.

Comment: I tested it in Linqpad and mistook the warning squiggly for an error.